# Parallel foreach with ConcurrentBag not working

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

Im stuck with this, and cant find how to solve it. 
I have a long running method that retrieves an object and inserts in a list. Im trying to make it Parallel to save some time, but the number of items are not the same.

Here is my code

```
        var listXls = new List<ReporteXlsPippPrfE>();

        foreach (var records in findItem)
        {

            var item = _plantillaPippBs.GetXlsProformaEpsByCveShcp(records.ftClaveCarteraSHCP);
            if (item != null)
                listXls.Add(item);
        }

        var ConcurrentlistXls = new ConcurrentBag<ReporteXlsPippPrfE>();

        Parallel.ForEach(findItem, records =>
        {
         var item = _plantillaPippBs.GetXlsProformaEpsByCveShcp(records.ftClaveCarteraSHCP);
         if (item != null)
             ConcurrentlistXls.Add(item);

       });
```

At the end, the ListXls object always retrieve 79 items and the ConcurrentlistXls object varies the number of items. I don´t know if I´m missing something.

Comment: That suggests the code in `GetXlsProformaEpsByCveShcp` is stateful and not thread safe.

Comment: AN idea is add a ConcurrentDictionary to the ForEach and record the ```int index``` of each iteration as ```Key``` and a message  for ```Value``` like ```dict.TryAdd(index + " " + item != null ? "Ref" : "null");```  This way you can look at the dictionary and get an idea of what happened.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. But, honestly, @zaitsman is almost certainly correct.

Comment: I'd test by putting a `lock` around access to `ConcurrentlistXls` and see if the problem remains or goes away.

Comment: So, what GetXlsProformaEpsByCveShcp method does, is connect to a database and execute an stored procedure so, they can fill a bussiness entitie (item) properties. I dont know how to make it safe thread.

Comment: putting a lock to the method doesnt help at all with the parallelism because it works almost like a foreach method.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It wasn't the method GetXlsProformaEpsByCveShcp that wasnt thread safe. 
What I did to solve it, was not use the Parallel.ForEach but a List < Task >, then added all the tasks and wait until all the Tasks has finished asynchronously. 
I checked the method (which call the database) and I saw that the procedure calling was inside a try catch block. 
When the method is called synchronously, the exception never happens. But when the method is executed 79 different times asynchronously, there is Time out in the connection.
So, it was solved only adding more time to the TimeOut properties of the SqlCommand object.

Finally, this is how I change my code

```
     var asyncBagTask = new List<Task>();
        var ConcurrentlistXls = new ConcurrentBag<ReporteXlsPippPrfE>();

        foreach (var records in findItem)
        {
            asyncBagTask.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {

                    var item = _plantillaPippBs.GetXlsProformaEpsByCveShcp(records.ftClaveCarteraSHCP);
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        ConcurrentlistXls.Add(item);
                    }


            }));
        }
      Task.WaitAll(asyncBagTask.ToArray());
```

Thanks to all.